# Running Jenkins says “package org.junit does not exist”

Tags: java, spring, jenkins, junit

When I run my test locally everything is fine but running Jenkins gives me

`“package org.junit does not exist”`.

My pom.xml is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

If I add:

```
<version>4.12</version>
```

it gives me "Duplicating managed version 4.12 for junit", so I removed it.

I tried instructions in similar posts like moving the test in the test directory, but I still have the same problem. Also tried to remove the test scope.

My class has @Test annotation as well.

Comment: Try removing scope test

Comment: @RoyShahaf I tried .. Now I double checked it and its the same result

Comment: Ok, what is your jenkins configured to do exactly?

Comment: @RoyShahaf I am java junior, I don't really understand the Jenkins config.. All I know is that it's Jenkins with Docker and every time I push a commit, Jenkins builds the project and runs the tests, so I can see the error that Junit package doesn't exist

Comment: Could you pls share (a) The Jenkinsfile (root of your directory) and (b) The POM.xml file (or the POM.xml files if there are multiple)?

Comment: Well, between jenkins and docker it's quite problematic to tell what is happening: are all your dependencies being downloaded using maven with a relevant pom file? are they all packaged and used in the docker file?
If you have the dockerfile available it can help.